# Finding duplicate values in row with Java

Tags: java, find, duplicates, row

So I've a file with these rows

```
155, 490, 297, 490,
-45, 19, 45, 19,
-24, 80,-12,-69, 80,
12,-92, 28,-40,
```

I try to read the file and find these rows which contain duplicate elements. But something with my logic is wrong and I can't find the error. Any help ?

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new Scanner( new File("array_list.csv"));
            String line;
            while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
                line = fileInput.nextLine(); 
                String[] lineArr = line.split(",");
                // check for missing values
                boolean contains = true;
                for(int i=0; i<lineArr.length; i++) {
                    for(int j=0; j<lineArr.length; j++) {
                        if(lineArr[i]==lineArr[j]) {
                            contains = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!contains) {
                        // print the row .....
                    }
                    else {
                        contains = true;
                        // print some thing ...
                    }
                }
            }
            } finally {
            if (null != fileInput) {
                fileInput.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error? is it a compilation error? or it is not behaving as you expected?

Comment: You are comparing strings. == is not the correct choice.  One otion is to use equals. Other (and more correct) is to convert to number and compare

Comment: another thing, if you want to avoid duplicate entries, try to use Set (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). It omits any duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're comparing strings, you need to use the `equals()` method:

```
lineArr[i].equals(lineArr[j])
```

That being said, there are a few other things I can see which may cause you problems:

- Be careful of spaces after commas. The sample data is inconsistent, so it's best to call `lineArr[i].trim()` to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace.
- You should set `contains` to false initially and try to find a match, *then* set it to true and break. Then `if (contains)`, print the row.
- The way your loops are set up, you will check each element with itself. So of course you will find a duplicate for each row!

Answer (score 1):

The problem that stands out to me immediately is that you are working with Strings, and you are currently using the "==" operator to compare strings on this line:

```
if(lineArr[i]==lineArr[j]) {
```

This should instead be:

```
if(lineArr[i].equals(lineArr[j])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your code as

```
if(lineArr[i].equals(lineArr[j]))
```

instead

```
if(lineArr[i]==lineArr[j])
```

The `equals()` method compares the actual content of the `Strings`, using the underlying `Unicode` representation, while `==` compares only the identity of the objects, using their `address` in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Put all values into a set and check if its length is equal to the original array. If so, then all values are unique, otherwise they are not:

```
while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
    line = fileInput.nextLine();
    List<String> lineArr = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
    if (new HashSet<String>(lineArr).size() != lineArr.size()) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare `String` using `equals()`.

Yet there are other issues in your code. At some point, `i` and `j` are equal and thus `lineArr[i]==lineArr[j]` will always be true.

A simple way for checking duplicates is to use a `Set` and check its size:

```
Set<String> lineSet = new HashSet<lineArr.length>;
for(String s : lineArr) {
    lineSet.add(s);
}
if(lineSet.size() < lineArr.length) {
    // there are duplicates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

```
    Scanner fileInput = null;
    try {           
        fileInput = new Scanner(new File("array_list.csv"));
        String line;
        while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {

            line = fileInput.nextLine(); 
            String[] lineArr = line.split(",");
            // check for missing values
            boolean contains = true;
            for(int i=0; i<lineArr.length; i++) {

                for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
                    if(lineArr[i].equals(lineArr[j])) {
                        contains = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            if(!contains) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            else {
                contains = true;
            }
        }
        } finally {
        if (null != fileInput) {
            fileInput.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for finding duplicate elements

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class StringManipulation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringManipulation manipulation=new StringManipulation();
        manipulation.findDuplicateElementList();
        //manipulation.findDuplicateElementbyMap();

    }

    private void findDuplicateElementList() {

        String lineData = "ashish manish ashish manish sachin manish ashish neha manish";

        String[] list = lineData.split(" ");

        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(list);

        // containingList=stringList;
        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
            int count = 0;
            String currVal = stringList.get(i);

            if (stringSet.contains(currVal)) {
                continue;
            } else {

                for (String string : stringList) {
                    if (currVal.equals(string)) {
                        stringSet.add(currVal);
                        count++;

                    }

                }
            }

            System.out.println("Occurances of " + currVal + " " + count);

        }
    }


}
```